# How to use dropbox with exFAT in Ubuntu?

Tags: 22.04, dropbox

I want to set up my Dropbox folder on a exFAT formatted USB drive, so that I can share it between different computers.

Dropbox tells me to move the dropbox folder to a "supported" drive. I know that ext4 works.

Is there any way to make Dropbox work with an exFAT drive in Ubuntu?

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Comment: (A lot of people down vote for no reason. Or they may think your question makes little sense.) That is a Dropbox limitation, not a setting in Linux or Ubuntu. It is up to you to change the format of the drive. Why don't you? If you use it in combination with Windows, use ntfs.

Comment: While this is a dropbox limitation, there might be workaround, which is why I asked the question. exFAT provides better performance than NTFS, and I am not sure if dropbox supports NTFS on Linux either

Comment: You could try NTFS, if it works with Dropbox in Ubuntu. You could also consider synchronizing the files in an ext4 file system and in the exFAT system of the USB drive (use for example `unison` for that purpose).